# For some reason, I can't change fontawesome icon colors

Tags: font-awesome

I have fontawesome called properly in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
```

and also at the bottom:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/js/all.js"></script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
         <div class="socials">  
            <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github-square"></i></a>

        </div>
```

And this is my style/sass:

```
.socials{     
    a{  
        margin-left: 1em; 
        fill: pink; 
        transition: .3s;
        font-size: 4em;

        &:hover{
            color: red;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

I can change the font-size and margin. But for some reason, I can't change the color. I saw that there might be an instance that I have used the SVG version instead and that fill property is the one that should be used, but still to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if [that's](https://codepen.io/SassCrafter/pen/ExyeyXJ?editors=1100) you want, then the problem is that you used square icons.

```
<div class="socials">
    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
</div>
.socials {
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 6rem;
    height: 6rem;
    font-size: 4rem;
    transition: 0.3s;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 6rem;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: still wouldn't work in my actual project, maybe there's something wrong with the whole css